# SherlockListFragment - how to put my adapter content in the R.id.content of fragment pager list?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have this code

```
public class MyFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
        MyFragment f = new MyFragment();

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list, container,false);
        View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        ((TextView)tv).setText("Layout One" );
        return v;
    }
}
```

I have created an adapter the contains the list of contacts and i want to put that list of contact in fragment_pager_list.
I am using this code

```
mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.fragment_pager_list, null,
                new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME},
                new int[] { R.id.text}, 0);

        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Start out with a progress indicator.
        setListShown(true);
```

How to show "Contacts" at top and my two contacts below it.

[image]

fragment_pager_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2011 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:drawable/gallery_thumb">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"/>

    <!-- The frame layout is here since we will be showing either
    the empty view or the list view.  -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <!-- Here is the list. Since we are using a ListActivity, we
             have to call it "@android:id/list" so ListActivity will
             find it -->
        <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

        <!-- Here is the view to show if the list is emtpy -->
        <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="No items."/>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How to reference the ListView in  FrameLayout in above xml ?

Comment: Give the FrameLayout an ID (such as `android:id="@+id/my_frame_list"`), then find it as a View in your code, then find the ListView child of it. Alternately, you can take a look at the link I provided in my answer, and it shows how to use a custom ID on the list. _(PS: I don't get notifications unless you reply to my answer or command. :P)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be extending `SherlockListFragment`. Then you can call `setListAdapter` on it ([documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#setListAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter))).

This has worked for me in the past:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_list_layout, container, false);

    setListAdapter(/* Your adapter, should extend BaseAdapter or similar */);

    return v;
}
```

**Edit**: Also, I believe your ListView must have ID `android:id="@android:id/list"`. If it doesn't work with that ID, try the solution found **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5159661/1438733)**.

Comment: I have solved my problem little bit by using this                         mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.fragment_pager_list, null,
                new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME},
                new int[] { R.id.text}, 0);

Comment: I have given screenshot of my emulator at top . In this i have two contacts so it must show a title Contacts and my two contacts below it. Still i am working on it because it is not done yet.

Comment: In the layout file that contains your ListView, why not just add a TextView above it? Something like **[this](http://pastebin.com/c4sMkHW9)**?

Comment: there is already a textview above my listview. you can check in fragment_pager_list.xml.

Comment: When using your exact XML file, my app displays the "Hello World!" string in the center of the screen above the "No items." of the empty list. Are you hiding the `TextView` programatically? If you want to play around, set the height of the `FrameLayout` to something like 100px and remove the `layout_weight` attribute to see if it's pushing it out of the layout.

Comment: No i am not hiding the text view. this works for me but this is not using my xml.

Comment: @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);        
       
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
           android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null,
                 new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME},
                 new int[] { android.R.id.text1}, 0);
    TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
    tv.setText("Contacts");
    this.getListView().addHeaderView(tv);
    
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

Comment: How can i use my fragment_pager_list.xml to create the same view like contacts text at top and list of contacts below it. my above code works fine please help me?

Comment: Ah, I see. No, there is no way to do this. The `addHeaderView` call is what adds the `TextView` to the `ListView` as a title. There is no way to do this through XML. It **must** be done through Java. The only way to have your `TextView` as a title for the `ListView` is through the same method that is seen in the XML example you provided.

Comment: I dont want to add anything in my xml dynamically. I just want to place "Contacts" text in my text view and list of contacts in my listview of above xml. How can i do this?

Comment: Then just change `"@string/hello_world"` to `"Contacts"` in the XML file you provided. (See also [String resource docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html).) You seem to already know how to populate the list. (The code you gave seems to work fine for you.)

Comment: When i put this line getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this); in either onCreate or onCreateView, then i found an error in log that it can't be used with custome content view.

Comment: @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      
     getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

Comment: public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle){View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list, container,false); View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text); ((TextView)tv).setText("Contacts" ); View lv = v.findViewById(android.R.id.list); ((ListView)lv).setTextFilterEnabled(true);     ((ListView)lv).clearChoices();    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null,  new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME}, new int[] { android.R.id.text1}, 0); ((ListView)lv).setAdapter(mAdapter);return v;}

Comment: First: Those codes are incredibly hard to read. Use a resource like [PasteBin](http://www.pastebin.com) to post whole code methods. Second: Comment threads should not end up this long... Third: Why are you even calling `initLoader`? It is not necessary to load your `ListView`. All you need to do is lay it out in the XML, then populate the adapter in code. That's it.

Comment: i am using loder to query the content provider and fetch the list of contact.

Comment: Then use ActionBarSherlock's `getSupportLoaderManager()` instead. It will use the Android v4 support library and should provide the requested behavior.